# CSS - max z-index value

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, z-index

Is there a maximum / minimum possible value for the CSS `z-index` property? 
Do different browsers have different maximum / minimum accepted values? 
How will browsers handle a high / low value?

I thought I read somewhere once about a max `z-index` value. Maybe I'm wrong. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Indranil Didn't see that question, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

These are the max values.

```
Browser         Max z-index value  When exceeded, value changes to:
Internet Explorer 6 2147483647  2147483647
Internet Explorer 7 2147483647  2147483647
Internet Explorer 8 2147483647  2147483647
Firefox 2           2147483647  *element disappears*
Firefox 3           2147483647  0
Safari 3            16777271    16777271
Safari 4            2147483647  2147483647
Chrome 29           2147483647  2147483647
Opera 9             2147483647  2147483647
```

Found it somewhere on the web.

Comment: Interesting! Does Chrome handle this the same way Safari does?

Comment: Found the same information here: http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/. So this can be the source. However, the information is from 2009.

Answer (score 17):

Incredibly, this is the chrome's max z-index value.

```
.css('z-index', '99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999').css('z-index')
```

If you add one more digit it will go to `1e+308`

Comment: I don't think so. I have the latest chrome now and anything greater than `2147483647` doesn't work.

Comment: The number you posted is one less than 1e+308 (10^308), so from your description I cannot follow why that should be the largest supported value. Did you try e.g. 1e310?

Comment: Actually setting anything above 2147483647 set the zIndex to 2147483647, i.e. 2^31-1. There is a difference between setting a value, and the value actually stored (and used) by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Found some newer information from 2012:

"Chrome, Opera and IE9 seem to be the only browsers supporting a true infinite value for the z-index, while Firefox is still using 2147483647 and Safari now engages in some strange rounding off behavior after a number exceeds 16 digits in length."

Here is the source:
[World War Z-index](http://joeist.com/2012/06/what-is-the-highest-possible-z-index-value/)