# DIV expanding over iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, iframe

Is it possible to get a custom context menu (`DIV`) expanding over several `iframes`?
I have 2 `iframes` (within a `DIV` each for some reason). In `iframe 1` I have a custom context menu (another `DIV`). When I right-click in `iframe 1` next to the border, the context menu appears under `iframe 2`:
[image: How it is]

This is how it should be:
[image: How it should be]

I already gave the context menu a `z-index` of 99.

**EDIT:**
Here are my 3 sites. The both `iframes` (`left`, `right`) and the `index`, where they are linked.
Sorry, I don't know how to import `iframes` into fiddlejs, so that I had to link them separately.

[index.html](http://jsfiddle.net/YkZSr/)
[left.html](http://jsfiddle.net/3GhXS/)
[right.html](http://jsfiddle.net/GgBUz/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and/or post the rest of your CSS?

Comment: What's the z-index for the iframes themselves?

Comment: have a look at the firefox 3d inspect option. It does not only look cool, but it can actualy be helpfull when figuring out z-index problems. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/3D_view

Comment: @Mooseman: How can I embed the iframes into Fiddle?

Comment: You can just set the `src` attribute to `#` for the fiddle.

Comment: Can you add logic to intelligently position the context menu?  In other words if it's close to the edge of its iFrame, re-position it.  That's what our tooltip script does.  I've used this approach in Unity games as well.

Comment: All these people talking about `z-index` don't know what they're talking about. An iframe acts as a little window; something inside it will stay inside it. You can, however, put something over both iframes if it is in the containing page. You can use javascript to communicate between iframe and page to display the popup where you need it. With that change, z-index will actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `z-index: 1` for both `iframe`s. Keep the div with "context menu" at `z-index:99`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you floating the div?

```
.contextmenu{float: left; z-index: 999999}
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```
z-index: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

thats what i do when i want something to float on top of everything else.

Comment: Perhaps a little too much? Even without considering the hassle of hiving to go fetching your div back from its orbit around mars, most browser will simply cap that to some value or another (like pointed out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565821/css-max-z-index-value)) ;)

Comment: and what happens when somebody wants to put something on top of *that*? Use sensible numbers in `z-index`. Even multiples-of-1000 makes more sense than this. Besides `z-index` won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add logic that intelligently positions your context menu.

In other words, add code that re-positions the *context menu div* if it gets too close to the edge of the iFrame.

In other words:

**IF** *popup's x-position* **IS GREATER THAN** ( *iFrame's size* **MINUS** *popup's width* )

**THEN** reposition *popup window* to the left

This process is sometimes referred to as *clamping* the position of your context menu.

**NOTE**:

This will not be elegant unless the end user is aware of a logical separation between the two iFrames.