# Css–selector for when a html-document is inside an iframe?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a css-selector that assigns diffrent properites based on weather the html is inside an iframe or not. I tried this:

```
html:not(:root) body {
    background: black !important;
}
```

I expect this to apply `background: black;` to the body if it's inside an iframe, but it doesn't, why? And are there any css options? I could always check with javascript if html is root.

IE8 support not requierd.

Comment: The body is sometimes displayed inside an iframe as a widget on third party site, and sometimes it's displayed on it's own.

Comment: You can't apply CSS from outside the iframe. An <iframe> is its own world. If the domains etc. match, then Javascript can communicate in and out, and could (if it wanted to) inject CSS into a child frame. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286178/can-i-apply-css-to-the-elements-within-an-iframe

Comment: Responded and then saw your concession that you could always use javascript, which was exactly what I was suggesting. From what I understand of how CSS operates within frames, I don't it is an option here :(

Comment: This will put some light on your issue, please [review this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428067/apply-css-to-html-but-not-iframe-html)

Comment: @Sunil Kumar: That question is of a very different nature though.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

CSS is only scoped within the same document. An iframe is an entire document in its own right, and so a CSS rule that applies to the page that *contains* that iframe cannot apply to the page that's *within* that iframe.

This means that as far as HTML and CSS are concerned, `html` is **always** `:root` (and therefore can **never** be `:not(:root)`).

Unless you are able to transfer this CSS from the containing page to the page within the iframe (using a script for example), I don't believe there is a way using just CSS.

Comment: They work very differently. Like I said, CSS is strictly per-document.

Answer (score 29):

It is probably possible to do the styling in an iframe with JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.body.querySelector('#some-element').style.background-color = 'red';
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure that the iframe is on the same domain, otherwise you can't get access to its internals. That would be cross-site scripting.

Accessing elements inside iframes with JavaScript document futher here: [Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Comment: Using JS for detection is good, butd on't do the styling in JS: make the detection of the framing in JS, put a class (or data attribute) depending on the detection result, and apply your usual CSS file using this new class/data-attribute selector (this separates responsibilities, and allows using strict CSP)

Comment: @Xenos what do you mean by "new class/data-attribute selector"?

Comment: Do `if (window.parent !== window) { document.documentElement.classList.add('inside-iframe'); }` + `html.inside-iframe { /* properties */ }` with both codes in the iframed-html page (JS detection code in parent frame would be like `document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(i => i.contentDocument.documentElement.classList.add('inside-iframe'));` if prefered

Answer (score 2):

Posting my comment as an answer for better display, you should:

- Put "is in iframe" detection code in JS, as I don't see any other way of doing so
- Put CSS code inside the iframe depending on the JS result

So if all code is inside the iframe, do:

```
if (window.parent !== window) {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('inside-iframe');
}
```

```
html.inside-iframe {
    bkacground-color: black;
}
```

If you want the detection-JS-code to be inside the parent frame, go for:

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe')
    .forEach(i => i.contentDocument.documentElement.classList.add('inside-iframe'));
```

Assuming the iframe is loaded when executing this JS (otherwise, contentDocument/documentElement will not exist). You may rely, in such case, on `load` event of the iframe (but it seems better anyway to put "is-in-iframe" detection indise the iframe itself, as the corresponding CSS is inside the iframe too)

Answer (score 0):

```
let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[name="marco"]');
let ele = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector("#someElement")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
html:not(root) body {
    background: black !important;
}
```

Works

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome 39, and I don't think it will on any other browser.