# change css element inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have one probleme with iframe in my website i can't change css of some element inside the iframe. this the html of iframe when i inspect code via chrome.
i want to change the value of div under div class with class width-100.
i already try a lot of code without success.
i found this solution but i dont understand
/*******/
CSS is only scoped within the same document. An iframe is an entire document in its own right, and so a CSS rule that applies to the page that contains that iframe cannot apply to the page that's within that iframe.

This means that as far as HTML and CSS are concerned, html is always :root (and therefore can never be :not(:root)).

Unless you are able to transfer this CSS from the containing page to the page within the iframe (using a script for example), I don't believe there is a way using just CSS.
[Css–selector for when a html-document is inside an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842373/css-selector-for-when-a-html-document-is-inside-an-iframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)
/*******/
[image]

Comment: Please, [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Instead copy the [relevent code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in the question as text.

Comment: Also, did you meant to tag javascript instead of java? They are two very different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$('iframe').contents().find("width-100 div").css('height', '200px');
```